# Creating a CFDictionary

Tags: swift, core-foundation

In an attempt to get this following code to work:

import ImageIO

```
if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(self.URL, nil) {
    let options: CFDictionary = [
        kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: max(size.width, size.height) / 2.0,
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent: true
    ]

    let scaledImage = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, options).flatMap { UIImage(CGImage: $0) }
}
```

I need to know how to correctly initialize a `CFDictionary`. Unfortunately, it seems like it's not as easy as I predicted. 
I've done some experimenting and research, and it seems like there is conflicting information.

For starters, here's an entry in the Apple Docs regarding the `kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize` key:

> **kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize**
>
> The maximum width and height in pixels of a thumbnail. If this key is not specified, the width and height of a thumbnail is not limited and thumbnails may be as big as the image itself. If present, this key must be a CFNumber value. This key can be provided in the options dictionary that you pass to the function CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex.

After looking into how to initialize the `CFNumber`, I found an excerpt for `CFNumber`

> CFNumber is “toll-free bridged” with its Cocoa Foundation counterpart, NSNumber. This means that the Core Foundation type is interchangeable in function or method calls with the bridged Foundation object

I then tried to do this:

```
let options: CFDictionary = [
    kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: NSNumber(double: 3.0)
]
```

and was greeted by the error message: `'_' is not convertible to 'CFString!'` and `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your working code:

```
func processImage(jpgImagePath: String, thumbSize: CGSize) {

    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(jpgImagePath, ofType: "") {
        if let imageURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path) {
            if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(imageURL, nil) {

                let maxSize = max(thumbSize.width, thumbSize.height) / 2.0

                let options : [NSString : AnyObject] = [
                    kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize:  maxSize,
                    kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent: true
                ]

                let scaledImage = UIImage(CGImage: CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, options))

                // do other stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From Docs:

> The implicit conversions from bridged Objective-C classes
>   (NSString/NSArray/NSDictionary) to their corresponding Swift value
>   types (String/Array/Dictionary) have been removed, making the Swift
>   type system simpler and more predictable.

The problem in your case are the `CFStrings` like `kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize`. These are not automatically converted to String anymore.

reference from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874625/dictionary-now-gives-error-not-convertible-to-booleanliteralconvertible-since).

Comment: You can find example here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch10p507tabStops/TextTabTest/ViewController.swift